# Is this a bug in Reactor's Mono?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, project-reactor

I've noticed some strange behavior when using Reactor. The scenario is this:

- Make a call to a rest API endpoint, fetch a value, wrapped in a Mono
- Call another rest API endpoint with the above value, retrieve another value, wrapped in a Mono
- Zip the two results

What appears to happen is onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber) gets called twice for the first API call, which then opens two connections and produces two results. The result that gets passed to the second API call is non-deterministic and depends whether the second API call executes before or after the second of the two previous calls finishes.

This is code sample to reproduce the issue, using Kotlin and Springboot WebClient. The API endpoint either generates a single GUID, or a number of GUIDs depending on the path parameter. I use the first digit in the result of the first call as the path param in the second call:

```
val api = "https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/guid"
val client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(api)
        .build()

@Test
public fun reactorBug() {

    val firstResult = callApi().doOnSuccess { r -> println("callApi returned: $r") }
    val secondResult = callApi(firstResult).doOnSuccess { r -> println("callApi(result) returned: $r") }

    println(Mono.zip(firstResult, secondResult, { first, second -> "First result is ${first}Second result is $second" }).block())
}

private fun callApi(): Mono<String> {
    println("Calling Api")
    return client.get().retrieve().bodyToMono()
}

private fun callApi(number: Int): Mono<String> {
    println("Calling Api with $number")
    return client.get().uri("/{number}", number).retrieve().bodyToMono()
}

private fun callApi(firstResult: Mono<String>): Mono<String> {
    println("Extracting number from first result")
    return firstResult
            .map { guid -> guid.find { c -> c.isDigit() } }
            .map { Character.getNumericValue(it!!) }
            .flatMap { i -> callApi(i) }
}
```

This is an example output illustrating the issue:

> Calling Api
>   Extracting number from first result
>   callApi returned: 12ec857b-e42c-42ab-a7a2-69beb9a377e3
>   callApi returned: 5eedefa5-73b5-4995-aef3-8621e31b698d **<- this result shouldn't happen**
>   Calling Api with 5 **<- this should be 1, not 5**
>   callApi(result) returned:
>   01c64488-6a8c-4400-9094-6729c64a4e1a
>   0179beae-d2b4-40b6-8489-52fa58deb25f
>   8f814b1d-594c-4392-a4f5-04d417367add
>   45891d71-61b2-4d5b-81ad-2cfd8e453377
>   08edf0c3-3614-402b-8b17-000fdedce1a0
>   First result is 12ec857b-e42c-42ab-a7a2-69beb9a377e3
>   Second result is
>   01c64488-6a8c-4400-9094-6729c64a4e1a
>   0179beae-d2b4-40b6-8489-52fa58deb25f
>   8f814b1d-594c-4392-a4f5-04d417367add
>   45891d71-61b2-4d5b-81ad-2cfd8e453377
>   08edf0c3-3614-402b-8b17-000fdedce1a0

Edited debug output:

**30-01-2018 22:36:11.889 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.reactive.function.client.debug - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)**
30-01-2018 22:36:11.920 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.reactive.function.client.debug - request(unbounded)
30-01-2018 22:36:11.924 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil.debug - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
30-01-2018 22:36:11.925 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil.debug - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
30-01-2018 22:36:12.128 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil.debug - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
30-01-2018 22:36:12.129 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil.debug - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
30-01-2018 22:36:12.146 [main] DEBUG r.i.n.r.DefaultLoopEpollDetector.debug - Default epoll support : false
30-01-2018 22:36:12.156 [main] DEBUG r.i.n.resources.DefaultPoolResources.debug - New http client pool for www.uuidgenerator.net/173.255.225.224:443
30-01-2018 22:36:12.190 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.debug - -Dio.netty.processId: 4232 (auto-detected)
30-01-2018 22:36:12.396 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.debug - -Dio.netty.machineId: 78:e4:00:ff:fe:bf:a5:cb (auto-detected)
30-01-2018 22:36:12.447 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.debug - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
30-01-2018 22:36:12.448 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.debug - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
30-01-2018 22:36:12.448 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.debug - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
30-01-2018 22:36:12.459 [main] DEBUG r.i.n.c.PooledClientContextHandler.debug - Acquiring existing channel from pool: DefaultPromise@d23e4a(incomplete) SimpleChannelPool{activeConnections=1}
**30-01-2018 22:36:12.461 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.reactive.function.client.debug - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)**
30-01-2018 22:36:12.462 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.reactive.function.client.debug - request(unbounded)
30-01-2018 22:36:12.463 [main] DEBUG r.i.n.c.PooledClientContextHandler.debug - Acquiring existing channel from pool: DefaultPromise@c8295b(incomplete) SimpleChannelPool{activeConnections=1}
**30-01-2018 22:36:12.520 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG  r.i.n.resources.DefaultPoolResources.debug - Created [id: 0x88225196], now 2 active connections

30-01-2018 22:36:12.520 [reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG r.i.n.resources.DefaultPoolResources.debug - Created [id: 0x80971ff0], now 2 active connections**

Why does the first API call happen twice - is it a bug or is this the intended behaviour of Mono?

Comment: Because of `callApi(firstResult)`: you consume `firstResult` twice.

Comment: So why would that result in the API being called twice? Consuming the result twice I get, but the API should only be called once. (Using reactivex, this code worked as expected)

Comment: What is the suggested pattern for chained calls where the second needs the result from the first - block on the first call?

Comment: Just apply `doOnSubscribe()` to `firstResult` and print the current stacktrace to see who is calling. You'll see zip will subscribe to `firstResult` twice, once directly, once through that `map-map-flatMap` chain. What reactivex are you talking about. Use `flatMap` to do dependent flows. Also you don't need zip in this case but just keep the `firstResult` value around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the first api call happen twice

`zip` will subscribe to `firstResult` twice, once directly, once through that `map-map-flatMap` chain

You don't need `zip` in this case but just `flatMap` over and back:

```
val firstResult = callApi().doOnSuccess { r -> println("callApi returned: $r") }

val lastResult = firstResult
        .flatMap { first -> 
            Mono.just(first)
                .map { guid -> guid.find { c -> c.isDigit() } }
                .map { Character.getNumericValue(it!!) }
                .flatMap { i -> callApi(i) }
                .map { second -> "First result is ${first}Second result is $second" }
        }

lastResult.block()
```

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd. There is something I don't understand. I can see two subscriptions, I get that part, but why would that result in two API calls? The behaviour I would expect as a consumer of Mono is either for the second subscription to throw an exception when it attempts to resolve, or for it to do nothing, not for the underlying side-effect to happen twice, and silently. Or is the idea that multiple subscriptions on the same Mono will result in multiple results? Can you point me to any documentation that explains this behaviour?

Comment: I was using the RxJava type Single in an early iteration of this code and I *think* it was behaving as I would expect - I didn't observe two API calls. The switch to Mono introduced it.

Comment: Mono and Single by default are cold sources, that means every subscriber triggers a fresh execution. [See the documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold). It is possible your `Single` was cached but without the source code of the network call, I can't say for sure.

Comment: You say 'by default' - is there a way of configuring the behaviour of a Mono/Single such that they behave differently?

Comment: They are designed as such but you can apply operators to make them hot via cache() or toFlux().replay()